# Fast Click Instructions JS

Tags: javascript, fastclick.js, fastclick

I am trying to get fastclick.js to work for me in order to get rid of the delay of 300ms when clicking. For some reason, this is not working for me. I will show all of my steps taken in order to reproduce the problem. I would truly appreciate someone to tell me where I've gone wrong. Thank you!

1. Download [fastclick.js](https://github.com/ftlabs/fastclick) by clicking "download zip"
2. Extract zip file into my project
3. Add `<script type='application/javascript' src='fastclick.js'></script>`
4. Then, add the following code:

   ```
   if ('addEventListener' in document) {
       document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {
           FastClick.attach(document.body);
       }, false);
       }
   ```
5. Finally, run the project, and notice that the console says "FastClick is not defined", and that the 300ms problem still persists

Thank you for your time. I would appreciate if someone went through the steps of including fastclick in javascript code.

Comment: What does your html look like? What does your folder structure look like? Are you sure the src attribute is correct?

Comment: @christo8989 project -> www -> fastclick.js . I've tried www/fastclick.js, no luck

Comment: Where is your index.html?

Comment: projectName/www/index.html

Comment: You should be fine then.

Comment: @christo8989 Nothing seems to be working. Index.html and fastclick.js are in the same folder. FastClick is now defined, but doesn't do anything. There must be another problem.

Comment: Post your index.html code.

Comment: @christo8989 Most of my code is irrelevant. I am using an eventlistener "touchstart". I have an interval that updates an animation every 50ms. Fast click should be working. I might have downloaded the minified version of fast click, which requires origami. What is "Origami"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm assuming you add the scripts in the wrong order. Make sure `<script type='application/javascript' src='fastclick.js'></script>` is before your `<script type='application/javascript' src='main.js'></script>`.

I use the filename `main.js` to signify the javascript file that holds your code. You might have given it a different name like, `myJavascriptFile.js`.

```
<html>
  <script type='application/javascript' src='fastclick.js'></script>
  <script type='application/javascript' src='main.js'></script>
</html>
```

If this doesn't work then you probably have the wrong path to source. All the files should be in the same folder or you need to change the `src` path.

**EDIT:**

Here's an example index.html file.

```
<html>
<body>
  <div id="Console"></div>

  <!--<script type='application/javascript' src='https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/fastclick/1.0.6/fastclick.min.js'></script>-->
  <script type='application/javascript' src='https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/fastclick/1.0.6/fastclick.js'></script>
  <script>
    if ('addEventListener' in document) {
      document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {
        FastClick.attach(document.body);
      }, false);
    }

    // TEST: Print FastClick function to the div.
    var consoleDiv = document.getElementById("Console");
    consoleDiv.innerText = FastClick.toString();
  </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: I'll test this out

Comment: If I add the main.js script tag, an error occurs. Otherwise, no error occurs but fastclick.js has no effect. There is still a 300ms delay.

Comment: What is the name of the file with your javascript in it? Also, where is that file located?

Comment: It doesn't have a name, it is just <script>all my code</script>. But the .html file is called index.html

Comment: put it in a separate javascript file and load it in like above.

Comment: Nevermind, I fixed that canvas problem. Now everything works, except fastclick.js seems to not be doing anything (like before)

Comment: @AssafiCohen-Arazi I will post an example later.